# How do I access <c:set var> in a <%= scriptlet %>

Tags: jsp, jstl, scriptlet

I started following one tutorial about JSTL tags. The repositories tutorial used are too old, so I wanted to try it my way using some newer versions. Unfortunately, I am stuck now. I will tell you what I did, so I hope, you can help me out.

I downloaded 2 jar files from these two links: [api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/1.2.2), [implementation](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.5).

Jar files I got, I copied inside `WebContent/Web-INF/lib`. Now if I do this, I get an error:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
<body>

<c:set var="varA" value="hello world" />
<%=varA %> //varA cannot be resolved to a variable

</body>
</html>
```

To be honest I have no idea why we need import statement when *jar* files are literally in my project's `lib` folder. Also, does anyone know what is wrong here and why editor can't find my variable *varA*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variables set using JSTL tags can not be accessed **directly** with a scriptlet. There can be two ways to access `varA`.

**1. Using JSTL tags:**

```
<c:set var="varA" value="hello world" />
<c:out value="${varA }"></c:out>
```

**2. Using `pageContext.getAttribute`:**

```
<c:set var="varA" value="hello world" />
<%=pageContext.getAttribute("varA")%>
```

Comment: You are right. Can you tell me why do I need import statement at line 1 as well? Wasn't it enough that I copied jar files inside a lib folder?

Comment: I do not see any `import` statement in your question.

Comment: I meant on this `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`. How do you call this one then? :) And my question is why we need that line.

Comment: @Stefan - This is called the **taglib directive**. This is the way to tell the application server that you are going to use a taglib (e.g. the statement in your question informs the application server that you are going to use tags from the JSTL **core** taglib. Check [this](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-servlets/9780596516680/ch09s39.html) to learn more about it. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Thanks! And do you know why I can't access variables declared in JSTL it in "normal" scriplets?

Comment: @Stefan - You can access them but not directly. The second option in my answer is the way to access it with a scriplet. It's because the compiler can not see an attribute declared as a string literal.

Comment: Yeah, I tried code, you are correct. But why I can't do it simply directly? :/

Comment: @Stefan - As I have mentioned above, JSTL allows a variable to be declared as a string literal but java compiler cannot see it as the compiler never looks into the string literals (i.e. a valid string inside the double quotes). That can be discovered only by the runtime engine. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.